# Fish shell: how to wait for a background job and get its exit status?

Tags: shell, fish

I'm trying to figure out how to run multiple long-running commands in parallel in the fish shell, but with proper error handling so that my overall script/one-liner doesn't succeed unless they all do. But I can't figure out how to deal with exit status.

The [posix spec for `wait`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/utilities/wait.html) says that it should communicate exit status:

> The exit status returned by the *wait* utility shall be the exit status of the process requested by the last *pid* operand.

And the [GitHub thread](https://github.com/fish-shell/fish-shell/issues/1422) about adding `wait` to fish spends a lot of time discussing exit statuses (but then was closed suddenly years later without explanation). But it doesn't seem that `wait` actually does deal correctly with exit statuses in fish:

```
> ls nonexistent; echo $status
ls: cannot access 'nonexistent': No such file or directory
2

> ls nonexistent &; wait $last_pid; echo $status
ls: cannot access 'nonexistent': No such file or directory
0
fish: Job 1, 'ls nonexistent &' has ended
```

How can I wait for a background job to terminate and be able to tell whether it succeeded or not?

Answer (score 2):

`wait` does not yet expose the exit status, but you can get it with an `on-process-exit` event handler:

```
sleep 3 &
function sleep_ended --on-process-exit $last_pid
    echo "pid $argv[2] exited with status $argv[3]"
end
wait
```

Comment: That's helpful, thanks. (Is there a bug about `wait` returning the exit status?) But honestly I'm not sure I know shell scripting enough to figure out how to turn this into signaling an event that I can wait for to avoid exiting until both jobs finish. :-/